# complex ksoap in android java

Tags: java, android, ksoap

am trying to upload some data to a webservise in .net using ksoap java on android.
i have try to work it but with no success. the result is null and i have no idea why this is happen
the code that am using is the follow:

xml web service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <AddBloodPressure xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <PatientID>int</PatientID>
      <BloodPressure>
        <Sistolic>int</Sistolic>
        <Distolic>int</Distolic>
      </BloodPressure>
      <DateTimeStamp>dateTime</DateTimeStamp>
    </AddBloodPressure>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

the KvmSerializable code is

```
public class Category implements KvmSerializable
{
    public int Distolic;
    public int Sistolic;



    public int getDistolic() {
        return Distolic;
    }
    public void setDistolic(int distolic) {
        Distolic = distolic;
    }

    public int getSistolic() {
        return Sistolic;
    }
    public void setSistolic(int sistolic) {
        Sistolic = sistolic;
    }



    public Object getProperty(int arg0) {

        switch(arg0)
        {
        case 0:
            return getSistolic();
        case 1:
            return getDistolic();

        }

        return null;
    }

    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
        switch(arg0)
        {
        case 0:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            info.name = "Sistolic";
            break;
        case 1:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            info.name = "Distolic";
            break;
        default:break;
        }
    }

    public void setProperty(int arg0, Object arg1) {
        switch (arg0)
        {
        case 0:
            this.Sistolic = Integer.parseInt(arg1.toString());
            break;
        case 1:
            this.Distolic=Integer.parseInt(arg1.toString());
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

and my main is:

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);    
        request.addProperty("PatientId", "8");
      Category i1=new Category();
          i1.setDistolic(100);
      i1.setSistolic(100);
      PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
      pi.setName("BloodPressure");
      pi.setValue(i1);
     pi.setType(i1.getClass());
     request.addProperty(pi);                          request.addProperty("DateTimeStamp","2012-01-13");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet=true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    Object result=((Object)envelope.getResponse());
    String resultString=new String(result.toString());

}
```

ok. this is that am using. does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I belive that the timestamp property is incorrect. Ususally .net webservices format for timestamp is something like

```
yyyyMMddThhmmss
```

i can't remember the exact sintax

Comment: actually am not sure. am already using the same timestamp with other more easy webservices and it work with no problem. so i don't thing that this is the problem. actually i don;t know were is the error

Comment: you can try adding androidHttpTransport.debug = true;, then call the httpTransport.requestDump to check if the request is ok (this is done before androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
)

Comment: the httpTransport.requestDump it return me null. what ever this it means. i have no idea what the problem is. are correct the way that am doing the reguest of the webservice. on the same xml i have 2 simple request and 1 complex. are correct how i implement them?

Comment: ahh, sorry, the httpTransport.requestDump must be AFTER the androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); line